# Can't Access cPanel Subdomain?

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I recently created a domain and sub-domain via cPanel, and for some reason I cannot access that sub-domain today. I say today, because I was able to access it the other day, but without making any changes, I am no longer able to. I was, however, able to access this site from an external IP, though this site http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/.

I have tried accessing with IE8 and FF4, without any luck. Also, I am sure the domain(s) have propagated, because some of these have been active and used for months.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Comment: have you verified that the DNS is correct? and it doesn't conflict with any entries in your local DNS / DNS cache?

Comment: hmm... not real familiar with what you are talking about. my IT skills are definitely poor. How can I the DNS info. I don't have any root access to the server I am using.

Comment: don't need root access.  from a command prompt type nslookup domain.name (should work on both windows and *nix), and make sure you are getting the correct IP information, was what I meant.

Comment: should any of these requests timeout? the domains that work and the ones that don't all give the same response

Comment: no they should't time out.  If they timeout that could be the problem, Your computer cannot resolve the domains in questions. do you have direct access to the web, or are you being proxied?

Comment: yes, I have direct access to the web. an nslookup on google.com resolves to 6 ip addresses. The only proxy-like thing I have is an ad/web blocker. I have this disabled right now, though. There aren't any proxys on the network, just on the local computer.

Comment: well then there is your problem, if you cannot resolve the domain or the subdomain via DNS nothing else will work.

Comment: hmm... do you have any ideas on what I could do to remedy this?

Comment: hard to say. If can share the actual domain name/ sub domain I can look at the dns delegation info.  dig +trace domainname will trace from roots, and might provide some info. you can try flushing dns cache (might help, but probably not)

Comment: sure, some domains to try are bellmagazine.co.cc (working) and training.bellmagazine.co.cc (not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the domains

bellmagazine.co.cc and training.bellmagazine.co.cc

The main name servers are unraeachable at this time.  So the reason that bellmagazine.co.cc works is that an upstream server from you has the record cached.  But since it doesn't have training.bellmagazine.co.cc in the cache you cannot resolve it.

There is nothing that you can do, save for contacting the people that host the name servers. ns2.ismywb.com and ns1.ismywb.com and have them restore service to them.  Either that or move to domain hosting that has better uptime/nameservers.

Comment: The only thing I cannot understand is why the site is reachable via this site: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php. Try entering in one of the URLs, and you will get a preview of the site. Any idea?

Comment: perhaps you used their service before the DNS servers went south and they have the records cached as well.  If you know the IP addreses you can modify your system's hosts file and gain access to the site.  DNS information gets cached at lots of intermediate nodes, so my guess is that it already had it cached.  If the  NS servers don't come back, at somepoint the records will hit TTL and expire.

Comment: ok, thank your for your detailed descriptions, points up and answer accepted!